# Unable to handle multiple input type checkbox fields in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have this component where I have around 15 input type checkboxes, which upon checked/unchecked show/hide images. All fields have an `onChange`  handler which takes the category name of the images. The category type is then checked in a conditional and calls another helper function. All of them follows the same steps.

Now I'm trying to attach a local state to each of the checkboxes(all 15 of them) so that when one of them is checked it will show the respective category image and when unchecked it will hide the image.

Right now it is working but in reverse. I mean when it is checked it hides the image and shows it when unchecked. Also, on the first click on the checkbox, there is no response (no hide or show).

Here's the component. For simplicity's sake I'm only showing 3 fields. But there are around 15:

```
const Images= () => {

    const [ isNatureChecked, setIsNatureChecked ]       = useState( false );
    const [ isCityChecked, setIsCityChecked ]           = useState( false );
    const [ isAbstractChecked, setIsAbstractChecked ]   = useState( false );


    const handleImages = ( e, type ) => {

          if ( type === 'nature' ) {

                setIsNatureChecked( !isNatureChecked );
                showImage( 0, isNatureChecked && new Image.Nature() );

          } else if ( type === 'city' ) {

                setIsCityChecked( !isCityChecked );
                showImage( 1, isCityChecked && new Image.City() );

          } else if ( type === 'abstract' ) {
                
                setIsAbstractChecked( !isAbstractChecked);
                showImage( 2, isAbstractChecked && new Image.Abstract() );

          } 

     }

     return (
           <div>
                 <input type="checkbox" checked={isNatureChecked} onChange={( e ) => handleImages( e, 'nature' )} />
                 <input type="checkbox" checked={isCityChecked} onClick={( e ) => handleImages( e, 'city' )} />
                 <input type="checkbox" checked={isAbstractChecked} onClick={( e ) => handleImages( e, 'abstract' )} />
           </div>
      )
}
```

The first parameter in `showImage` func is the index.

How can I make the checkbox work in the right way? I mean when it will be checked, it will show image, and when it will be unchecked it will hide it.

Moreover, please suggest if this code can be refactored. 15 input fields will have 15 states and 15 conditionals. That's too many repetitive code which I want to avoid. So please suggest me the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

your handleImages function doesn't have an updated value which is why you don't see a change on the first click. You need to use the useEffect hook to dynamically show image and set the state value as a dependency.

A better way to approach this would be to create an object state e.g.

```
const [checkedImages, setCheckedImages] = useState({ nature: false, city: false, abstract: false });
```

and then your handler can switch the boolean states without any if else conditions.

```
    const handleChange = (e, type) => {
  setCheckedImages(prevState => ({...prevState, [type]: !checkedImages[type]}))
}
```

you will need a useEffect block to dynamically show images

lastly, the input fields can be mapped without having to write them one by one

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
    const Images= () => {
        const [imagesArr,setImagesArr] = useState([{name:'Nature',isChecked:false,index:0},{name:'City',isChecked:false,index:1},{name:'Substract',isChecked:false,index:2},])
        const handleImages = ( e, imageData,imageDataIndex ) => {
    
                    setImagesArr(arr=>{
                       let arr2 = [...arr]
                       arr2[imageDataIndex] = {...arr2[imageDataIndex],isChecked:e.target.checked}
                       return arr2
                    });
                    showImage( imageData.index, e.target.checked && new Image[imageData.name]() );
    
         }
    
         return (
               <div>
                     {
                       imagesArr && imagesArr.length && 
                       imagesArr.map((data,index)=>{
                       return (
                         <input type="checkbox" checked={data.isChecked} onChange={( e ) => handleImages( e, data,index )} />
                       )
                       }
                     }
                     
               </div>
          )
    }
```

Comment: Hi. How do you have access to ```imageData``` in the render block?

Comment: i didn't understand your question, do you mean inside return?

Comment: In the ```div``` where did you get ```imageData```?

Comment: you can use any state or variable thats inside component, inside jsx by use curly braces {imageData}  // { ...you can write javascript here }

Comment: Sorry there's some issues with your code. Checking one checkbox makes all the checkboxes true.

Comment: really sorry i mis-spelled something, i just checked i have edited my answer now try

Comment: Hi. You ```setImages``` is wrong. It changes the state of all the items when clicked on one input. Can you please fix it?

Comment: send your updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237964/discussion-between-harshit-upadhyay-and-s-khan).